# Can I toggle expandability of a expander?

Tags: wpf, xaml, expander

Is there any property or state I can set on a expander object that makes it unexpandable but still can be selected?

I'm thinking for example of the last Child in a TreeView where I don't wan't the Expander to have an expander button. But other uses could be if someone doesn't have access to more then the header or something along that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know would be to create custom control template for expander, remove expander button from it and disable expanding.

See [WPF Expander: Reversing the icon direction while keeping the content location (ExpandDirection) the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142407/wpf-expander-reversing-the-icon-direction-while-keeping-the-content-location-ex/3143161#3143161) on how to create custom template for expander.